# dpkg: Remove msodbcsql17

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to uninstall `msodbcsql17`:

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove msodbcsql17
(Reading database ... 198868 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing msodbcsql17 (17.9.1.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package msodbcsql17 (--remove):
 installed msodbcsql17 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 msodbcsql17
```

I've also tried with `apt remove`:

```
sudo apt remove msodbcsql17
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-shell : Depends: libffi7 (>= 3.3~20180313) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) but it is not installable
               Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Also:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  msodbcsql17 mysql-shell
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 127 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 198874 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing msodbcsql17 (17.9.1.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package msodbcsql17 (--remove):
 installed msodbcsql17 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 msodbcsql17
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas about how to remove it?

Answer (score 6):

I think i had the same issue.  In my case the problem was that the post-removal script of the package `msodbcsql17` located at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/msodbcsql17.postrm` is calling `odbcinst` - which was not installed on my system. What worked for me was to:

- first comment the two lines in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/msodbcsql17.postrm` that start with `odbcinst` and `db_purge` in the `remove` section.
- uninstall `msodbcsql17` with `sudo apt-get remove msodbcsql17`
- install `odbcinst` with `sudo apt-get install odbcinst`
- rerun the post-removal script with `sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/msodbcsql17.postrm remove`
- remove `odbcinst` with `sudo apt-get remove odbcinst`